# Angular 1.5.8 Component, get parent context in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am creating a dynamic menu with ng-click action template is configured in DB.

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" id="widget-{{$ctrl.id}}-context-menu">
    <li ng-repeat="Menu in $ctrl.menu">
        <a href="" ng-click="$parent.evaluateFn(Menu.Template)">{{Menu.Name}}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

1. How can I get reference to the parent context from ng-repeat so that I can parse the template string (eg. '$ctrl.handleClick('abc')') to make a click event? $parent and $ctrl are not working inside ng-repeat.
2. What is the correct way to convert a string to an ng-click event? 
   What should I do in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$scope` with components is always isolated, I am not sure you can access it that way and you shouldn't. What you need to do is bind the function from your parent controller/component.

Bind the function from the parent: (`$ctrl` is the parent here)

```
<my-component action="$ctrl.evaluateFn">
```

Add the binding to your component:

```
bindings: {
    action: '&'
}
```

Use it in your markup:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" id="widget-{{$ctrl.id}}-context-menu">
    <li ng-repeat="Menu in $ctrl.menu">
        <a href="" ng-click="$ctrl.action(Menu.Template)">{{Menu.Name}}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

You can use whatever you want instead of `action`.

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component

Comment: Here ng-click="$ctrl.action(Menu.Template)" won't work for me because I just need to invoke a function in the component controller, not a function in the page where the component is consumed.  Issue is, ng-repeat create another context within its block and I can't use "$ctrl" to refer the controller. I tried "$parent" but not working.

Comment: You can use `$ctrl` inside of `ng-repeat`. If this does not work, you have other problems. Provide a codepen please.